gnome network displays not working lubuntu 24.04 LTS
Installed gnome network displays with sudo apt install gnome-network-displays.
It finds both my Roku stick and my Hisense TV, it does not display the desktop to either. The TV screen goes blank for about a second when a connection is made but then returns to normal tv picture as connection is lost.
I have applied sudo ufw allow 7236/tcp comment 'allow gnome-network-displays' Ubuntu-restricted-extras is installed.
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all gnome-network-displays
(gnome-network-displays:13964): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 10:47:59.393: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gtk-DEBUG: 10:47:59.791: Connecting to session manager
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gtk-DEBUG: 10:47:59.792: Failed to get the GNOME session proxy: The name org.gnome.SessionManager is not owned
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gtk-DEBUG: 10:47:59.793: Failed to get the Xfce session proxy: The name org.xfce.SessionManager is not owned
(gnome-network-displays:13964): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 10:47:59.806: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Adwaita-DEBUG: 10:47:59.910: Setting org.freedesktop.appearance.contrast of type u not found
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Adwaita-DEBUG: 10:48:00.043: Using style /org/gnome/Adwaita/styles/defaults-light.css
(gnome-network-displays:13964): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 10:48:00.072: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.079: NdWindow: Got avahi client
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.082: NdWindow: Got avahi browser
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.490: NdNMDeviceRegistry: Found a new device, creating provider
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.491: WFDP2PProvider: Discover is now set to 1
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.491: WFDP2PProvider: Starting P2P discovery.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-WARNING **: 10:48:00.492: Failed to create screencast session: CreateSession failed
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.519: NdNMDeviceRegistry: Got NMClient
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.519: NdPulseaudio: Querying sink info by name
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.526: NdPulseaudio: Error querying sink info
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.526: NdPulseaudio: Got a sink info for the expected name
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:00.914: WFDP2PProvider: Started P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:11.520: WFDP2PProvider: Found a new sink with peer "Living Room TV" (BE:5C:17:58:ED:C2) on device 0x5f5b8993a020
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:11.520: NdWFDP2PSink: Adding P2P MAC BE:5C:17:58:ED:C2 to match list
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:11.520: MetaSink: Priority sink updated. Priority: 100
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:11.520: SinkList: Adding a sink
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.253: Found openh264enc for video encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.253: Found x264enc for video encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.253: Found avenc_aac for audio encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.254: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_ENSURE_FIREWALL
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.260: WFDP2PProvider: Discover is now set to 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.260: WFDP2PProvider: Stopping P2P discovery.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.278: NdFirewalld: Firewalld does not seem to be installed. Code will assume that no firewall will be configured.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.278: NdWfdP2PSink: Got firewall information
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.278: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_WAIT_P2P
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.397: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 40. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.397: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 50. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.398: NdWfdP2PSink: Got P2P connection
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.398: Found openh264enc for video encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.398: Found x264enc for video encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.398: Found avenc_aac for audio encoding.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:19.399: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_WAIT_SOCKET
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:27.170: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 70. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:31.808: NdWfdP2PSink: Got client connection
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:31.808: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_WAIT_STREAMING
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:31.829: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 80. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:31.875: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 90. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:31.875: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 100. Reason: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.312: WfdClient: OPTIONS querying done
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.318: WFD query params
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.320: WfdClient: GET_PARAMS done
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.320: Add audio codec to params:
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.320: WfdAudioCodec: AAC, 7, latency: 0
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321: Add codec to params:
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321: WfdVideoCodec:
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * profile: 1
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * level: 8
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * native: 640x480 60p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321: Supported resolutions:
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 800x480 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 854x480 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 864x480 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 640x360 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 960x540 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 848x480 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1280x720 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1920x1080 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 800x600 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1024x768 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1152x864 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1280x768 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1280x800 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1360x768 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1366x768 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1280x1024 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1400x1050 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1440x900 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.321:  * 1600x900 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.322:  * 1680x1024 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.322:  * 1680x1050 30p
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-WARNING **: 10:48:32.322: WfdClient: No resolution found, falling back to standard FullHD resolution.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.322: selected resolution 1920, 1080 @30
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.324: WfdClient: SET_PARAMS done
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.326: WfdClient: Initialization done!
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.385: use x11: 1
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:32.703: WfdMedia init: Got 1 streams
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:35.255: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_ERROR
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:35.264: WFDP2PProvider: Device state changed. It is now 30. Reason: 8
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.752: An audiocodec has been selected: yes
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.754: WfdMedia: Finalize
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.755: Got state change notification from streaming sink to state ND_SINK_STATE_DISCONNECTED
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.759: WFDP2PProvider: Discover is now set to 1
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.759: WFDP2PProvider: Starting P2P discovery.
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.759: WfdClient: Finalize
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.759: WfdServer: Finalize
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.759: WfdMediaFactory: Finalize
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:37.798: WFDP2PProvider: Started P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:57.646: WFDP2PProvider: Restarting P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:48:57.690: WFDP2PProvider: Started P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:49:17.645: WFDP2PProvider: Restarting P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:49:17.698: WFDP2PProvider: Started P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:49:37.645: WFDP2PProvider: Restarting P2P discovery
(gnome-network-displays:13964): Gnd-DEBUG: 10:49:37.696: WFDP2PProvider: Started P2P discovery
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ NETWORK_DISPLAYS_DUMMY=1 gnome-network-displays
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.369: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.370: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.462: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.462: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.463: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.463: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.463: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.463: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.464: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.464: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.464: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.465: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.465: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.465: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.466: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.466: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.466: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.466: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.467: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.467: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.479: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.479: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.480: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.480: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.480: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.480: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.481: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.481: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.481: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.482: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.482: gst_value_collect_int_range: assertion 'collect_values[0].v_int < collect_values2.v_int' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:7827): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 10:49:57.482: range start is not smaller than end for `GstIntRange'
(gnome-network-displays:7826): Gnd-WARNING **: 10:50:01.330: Failed to create screencast session: CreateSession failed
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ nmcli device
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION
wlo1          wifi      connected                              vodafone720982
p2p-dev-wlo1  wifi-p2p  connecting (getting IP configuration)  Wi-Fi P2P Peer BE:5C:17:58:ED:C2
lo            loopback  connected (externally)                 lo
eno1          ethernet  unavailable
martyn@martyn-hp255g1notebookpc:~$ iw dev
phy#0
Interface p2p-wlo1-1
ifindex 5
wdev 0x3
addr a6:db:30:4c:b4:ff
ssid DIRECT-95
type P2P-GO
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
txpower 16.00 dBm
multicast TXQ:
qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes        tx-packets
0       0       42      0       0       0       0       9903            42
Interface wlo1
ifindex 3
wdev 0x1
addr a4:db:30:4c:b4:ff
type managed
channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
txpower 16.00 dBm
multicast TXQ:
qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes        tx-packets
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0               0
I have these GStreamer plug-ins:


I have these GStreamer plug-ins

Do I need these installed?                                                                                                                 libavahi-client-dev
libavahi-gobject-dev
libgtk-3-dev
libnm-dev
libpulse-dev
libprotobuf-c-dev
libjson-glib-dev
libsoup-3.0-dev      I installed using APT, but I think these are for the flatpak version?
